# the correct structure relation between student vs teacher comparing to user table

Tags: database, laravel, database-design, relational-database, relationship

What is the correct database structure design for user table if I have `instructor` vs `student`?

Is it correct to create each one in separate table and the id is the user table

Like this?:

[image: table design]

Or creating new flag field (1 or 2) to define the `students` from the `instructors` like this?:

[image: table design2]

I know both will work, but I'm asking to get the most professional answer for this problem.

For me i'm working on Laravel and creating a relations there is very easy.

Comment: You can use type column for user table

Comment: @EtibarRustemzade  I know i can use type , but i need the profession one,

Answer (score 2):

The first option - separate tables for each subtype of user - is recommended when you have subtype-specific attributes, relationships or constraints; and a known fixed set of subtypes.

The second option - a type indicator column - is recommended when you don't have any subtype-specific attributes, relationships or constraints; and works better for user-managed subtypes.

It doesn't matter whether you have overlapping or disjoint subtypes. Either can be recorded in separate tables; or overlapping subtypes can be indicated via multiple boolean fields and disjoint via a single field.